Which of the Elementary Column Operations will not change the solution of SLE
Which of the elementary column transformations, (except for interchanging the columns), will not change the solution of the system of linear equations?
I found a definiton:

Definition 2.2.1 An elementary row operation is an operation that does not change the domain of truth of the SLR represented by this matrix.
Such adjustments are:


row replacement
multiplying a row by a non-zero real number
adding a linear combination of other rows to a row
omitting a row that is a linear combination of other rows
omitting a null row

And i want to know which of them cannot be used for column transformations to solve a system of linear equations.

You may want to ask this over on the [math.se] website, as this isn't really related to programming. It's just a linear algebra question.
